# Wordpress Register Form

Tags: user-registration, wp-login-form

How can I make the username field have a default value on the register form?

I've seen that the core code is from the wp-login.php file but I do not want to edit that for obvious reasons.

I would like the username to be random integer and was looking at using a mt_rand() or something similar in place and then hide the field.

Thanks